# Flex with one fixed width column and one fluid column that must fill the remaining space

Tags: css, flexbox

Is there a way in CSS to have one column with a fixed width, and the second column filling whatever space remains in the row?

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.col1 {
  height: 100px;
  flex: 0 0 80px;
  background: red;
}

.col2 {
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
}
```

I suspect it's impossible with pure CSS, but if there is a solution then what is the solution?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/goldorak/4qsbvk3f/4/)

Comment: add `flex-grow: 1` to `.col2`

Comment: Oh yes that works, thanks! If you make an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: someone already posted an answer, you should accept that as an answer :)

Comment: Yes he posted it 3 minutes after my comment so I guess he was writing his answer while I posted the comment :) Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [`flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) shorthand property you can use `flex: 1` on `.col2` which specifies a `flex-grow` value. You could also as @Yousaf mentioned, explicitly define the `flex-grow` value by using `flex-grow: 1`.

The [`flex-grow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow) CSS property sets the flex grow factor of a flex item's [main](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox/#main-size) size. In other words, `flex-grow` makes a flex item occupy all of the free space on the main-axis.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.col1 {
  height: 100px;
  flex: 0 0 80px;
  background: red;
}

.col2 {
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
  flex: 1;
  /* flex-grow: 1; This also works! */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col1"></div>
  <div class="col2"></div>
</div>
```